# Compressing a structure definition into a single line and make two copies with sed

Tags: c, unix

There has been an attempt at this question already, [Detecting and concatenating a multi-line structure using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692359/detecting-and-concatenating-a-multi-line-structure-using-sed), but none of the answers worked for my specific case.

I have a program written in c which has two kinds of multi-lined structures.  I need to figure out how to use the unix utility sed to compress these structure definitions to a single line and then make two copies, so there are three copies of the structure definition in total.

Here is my c program example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct {
    int numer;
    int denom;
} Rational;

int main()
{
    struct node head;
    Rational half, *newf = malloc(sizeof(Rational));

    head = (struct node){ 5, NULL };
    half = (Rational){ 1, 2 };
    *newf = (Rational){ 2, 3 };

    return 0;
}
```

I know that the sed command will look something to the extent of `sed '/ *struct .*/N;' test.c` to find the structure and then a branch statement to append the rest of the lines of the structure definition to the single line.

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: The hard part is detecting when the struct *ends*; that's a C parsing problem, pretty heavy for sed. And why do you want to do this horrible thing anyway?

Comment: It's a homework problem.  The ultimate goal is to have the program compile for c89 so I have to change the struct declarations.

Comment: Technically no, but my professor told us his implementation was done with sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it.  Have a file which calls sed -f  and then create a file with a list of sed commands.  The  file goes as follows.

```
/typedef struct/b a
/^struct.*{/!b;:a;N
/}/!b a;p
s/\n//g
```